# Merging two words together letter by letter in php. How to make it work?

Tags: php, merge, words

How to merge two words together letter by letter in php on the following way:

Input #1: Apricot

Input #2: Kiwi

Expected output: AKpirwiicot.

So that if one word's characters are more than the other, it simply writes it down until the end.

I tried it by this logic:

```
Input smthing
str_split()
array_merge()
```

But I failed. Any solutions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def str_merge(a, b):
    s = ''
    k = min(len(a), len(b))
    for i in range(k):
        s += a[i] + b[i]
    s += a[k:] + b[k:]
    return s
```

In PHP:

```
function merge($a, $b)
{
    $s = '';
    $k = min(strlen($a), strlen($b));
    for($i=0; $i<$k; $i++)
    {
        $s = $s . $a[$i] . $b[$i];
    }
    $s = $s . substr($a, $k) . substr($b, $k);
}
```

Please forgive my PHP, not my strongest language...

Comment: It's not in php I suppose. Could you convert it to php?

Comment: Oh, I just noticed the PHP tag. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Dear Nikki, I'd like to contact you with some further questions. If I may, please leave a message on somos.connaissance@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

`$string1` and `$string2` can be in any order.

```
$string1=str_split("Apricot");
$string2=str_split("Kiwi");

if(count($string2)>count($string1)){
   $templ = $string1;
   $string1 = $string2;
   $string2 = $temp;
}

$result = "";
foreach($string1 as $key => $var){
{
    $result.=$var;
     if(isset($string2[$key])){
        $result.$string2[$key];
    }
}
echo $result;
```

`Array_merge()` also sticks one array on the end of the other so it wouldn't do what you are looking for I believe.

edit : ive adjusted to take into account no order, like @nikkis answer.